# Direct sum of Morphism ? Decomposition in irreductible representations.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Context : Finding irreductible representations such as a G module is a direct sum of these latter.

In a course i find the notation :

$p_4=p_1^{\oplus i_1} \oplus p_2^{\oplus i_2} \oplus p_3^{\oplus i_3}$ where $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are representations , seen as morphism , for example :
$p_i : G \rightarrow Gl(V_i)$.

Usually , we write the decomposition in irreductible G modules in terms of vectorial space associated ,for example $V_4=V_1^{\oplus i_1} \oplus V_2^{\oplus i_2} \oplus V_3^{\oplus i_3}$ where $V_i$ are complex vectorial spaces of irreductible representations.

Can someone explain what means the direct sum of morphism , or the notation of "direct sum of morphism" that i written ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two representations $p : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ and $q : G \to \mathrm{GL}(W)$,  $p \oplus q$ is the representation of $G$ on $V \oplus W = V \times W$ (i.e. $p \oplus q : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V \oplus W)$) given by
$$
  (p \oplus q)(g)(v, w) = (p(g)(v), q(g)(w)).
$$

This is really the same as your $V \oplus W$ because if you consider $V$ and $W$ as $G$-modules that basically just means that you hide the morphisms $p$ and $q$ from the notation and write $gv$ for $p(g)(v)$ if $v \in V$ and $g w$ for $q(g)(w)$ if $w \in W$. (That is, you decide whether to use $p$ or $q$ depending on which space the vector is from. Decomposing the morphism makes this implicit in the notation instead.)